# Get current text on input change in angular-selectize

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selectize.js

I'm using this [angular port](https://github.com/machineboy2045/angular-selectize) for selectize. I have two selectize elements in my view, both of which have thousands of options that will need to be shown to the user, but I don't think it's a good idea to query all of them at once and then offload that onto the user's computer.

Instead, I want to listen on angular selectize's inputs for keyboard changes, and then send the current text input value back to the server to get back a shorter list of options for autocompletion.

In jQuery, it would be something similar to:

```
$(".selectize-input_1").on('input', function() {
    var current_text = $(".selectize-input").val();
    $.get("/autocomplete", current_text, function(options) {
         // Set new autocomplete options for selectize
    });
})
```

For angular-selectize, I have my angular service that does an `$http.post(current_text)`, but I'm not quite sure how to listen for changes in the text input (and to get the current text value). The [original selectize usage](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md) suggests `onChange` event and `query` for raw_input would be the way to go. However, the following does nothing:

```
$scope.config_one = {
    create: true,
    valueField: 'id',
    labelField: 'name',
    delimiter: ',',
    onChange: function(value) {
        // Nothing happens when typing into input
        console.log(value);
    }
}
$scope.options_one = ['one', 'two']

<selectize config="config_one" options="options_one" ng-model="test"></selectize>
```

And I'm not sure how to get `query`. How do I listen for changes on input and grab the current text?

Answer (score 3):

The onChange() event only fires after the input box loses focus, to track key events use the onType() event.

Instead of:

    `onChange: function(value) {
        // Nothing happens when typing into input
        console.log(value);
    }`

Try:

    `onType: function(value) {
        console.log(value);
    }`